# Place QProgressBar text outside

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

On my Windows machine text is displayed to the right of the progress bar.

[image: progress bar on windows]

On my Linux machine text appears in the middle of the progress bar.

[image: progress bar on Linux with GTK+-based DE]

If I apply style to progress bar, text appears inside on both systems. How do I get it to appear outside, like in default Windows style?

[image: styled progress bar]

---

Here's the simplified version of the code I used to play with progress bars:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    auto widget = new QWidget;

    auto layout1 = new QVBoxLayout;
    widget->setLayout(layout1);

    auto layout2 = new  QHBoxLayout;
    auto progressBar = new QProgressBar;
    auto spinBox = new QDoubleSpinBox;
    spinBox->setRange(0,100);
    spinBox->setDecimals(1);
    spinBox->setSingleStep(1);
    progressBar->setRange(0, 10000);
    connect(spinBox, qOverload<double>(&QDoubleSpinBox::valueChanged), progressBar,
            [spinBox, progressBar]
            {
                progressBar->setValue(spinBox->value() * 100);
                progressBar->repaint();
            });

    layout2->addWidget(spinBox);
    layout2->addWidget(progressBar);

    auto textEdit = new QPlainTextEdit;
    auto stylesheet = R"(
QProgressBar {
   background-color: cyan;
   border-radius: 1px;
   text-align: right;
}

QProgressBar::chunk {
   background-color: magenta;     
   border-radius: 1px;
}
)";
    textEdit->setPlainText(stylesheet);
    connect(textEdit, &QPlainTextEdit::textChanged, progressBar,
            [textEdit, progressBar]
            {
                progressBar->setStyleSheet(textEdit->toPlainText());
            });


    layout1->addLayout(layout2);
    layout1->addWidget(textEdit, 1);

    setCentralWidget(widget);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use a margin.  If you change the QProgressBar section of your stylesheet to this:

```
QProgressBar {
   background-color: cyan;
   border-radius: 1px;
   text-align: right;
   margin-right: 4em;
}
```

then the right end of the progress bar will stop short of the text (which is right-aligned), resulting in the effect you are looking for.